# Heroku app crashing when deployed with error H10

Tags: django, heroku

I'm facing problem after deploying my django project on heroku. 
Please guide me where I'm going wrong.

I'm getting an Application Error when I visit my page online

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>    served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

These are the logs I copied from my terminal. I have done something wrong with gunicorn i guess.

```
(defcon)siddharth@s7h:~/Documents/python/defcon/s7h$ heroku logs
 ▸    Error parsing /home/siddharth/.heroku/cacert.pem
2015-05-21T17:21:15.506755+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2015-05-21T17:21:15.507020+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 292, in halt
2015-05-21T17:21:15.507265+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2015-05-21T17:21:15.506894+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 196, in run
2015-05-21T17:21:15.506988+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2015-05-21T17:21:15.507124+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2015-05-21T17:21:15.507157+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 343, in stop
2015-05-21T17:21:15.507311+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
2015-05-21T17:21:15.507387+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2015-05-21T17:21:15.507710+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2015-05-21T17:21:15.507555+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2015-05-21T17:21:15.507439+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
2015-05-21T17:21:16.397089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-05-21T17:21:16.413996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-21T17:21:16.415171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-05-21T17:21:22.644960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn defcon.wsgi`
2015-05-21T17:21:24.824895+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-21T17:21:24.824916+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2015-05-21T17:21:24.824925+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2015-05-21T17:21:24.824968+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825035+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 185, in run
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825010+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825089+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825112+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825171+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825148+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825223+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.manage_workers()
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825247+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825337+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.spawn_workers()
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825361+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 542, in spawn_workers
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825461+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825484+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825549+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825573+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825660+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2015-05-21T17:21:24.825756+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2015-05-21T17:21:25.588851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-05-21T17:21:25.604619+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-21T17:22:43.417115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blooming-shore-2021.herokuapp.com request_id=8c82dc58-7845-48b8-950d-0209cbe8692d fwd="182.69.224.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-21T17:22:44.330618+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blooming-shore-2021.herokuapp.com request_id=b5970670-760b-466e-af86-548cc1a84cd8 fwd="182.69.224.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-21T17:42:33.570495+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 551e2ed by siddharth.s1312@gmail.com
2015-05-21T17:42:33.570495+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by siddharth.s1312@gmail.com
2015-05-21T17:42:33.673029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-05-21T17:42:38.103054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn defcon.wsgi`
2015-05-21T17:42:40.083855+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-21T17:42:40.083924+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2015-05-21T17:42:40.084096+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2015-05-21T17:42:40.084049+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2015-05-21T17:42:40.084248+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 185, in run
2015-05-21T17:42:40.084200+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2015-05-21T17:42:40.084352+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2015-05-21T17:42:40.084412+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
2015-05-21T17:42:40.084506+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2015-05-21T17:42:40.084545+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run
2015-05-21T17:42:40.084655+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.manage_workers()
2015-05-21T17:42:40.084694+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
2015-05-21T17:42:40.085512+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.spawn_workers()
2015-05-21T17:42:40.085556+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 542, in spawn_workers
2015-05-21T17:42:40.085774+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
2015-05-21T17:42:40.085732+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2015-05-21T17:42:40.085885+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2015-05-21T17:42:40.085925+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
2015-05-21T17:42:40.086346+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2015-05-21T17:42:40.086720+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2015-05-21T17:42:40.908662+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-05-21T17:42:40.916834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-21T17:42:40.917785+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-05-21T17:42:45.761200+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn defcon.wsgi`
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212018+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212037+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212068+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212102+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212149+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212183+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 185, in run
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212227+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212248+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212292+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212297+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212355+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.manage_workers()
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212610+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212505+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 542, in spawn_workers
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212380+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212687+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212482+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.spawn_workers()
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212631+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212795+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212707+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
2015-05-21T17:42:48.212901+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2015-05-21T17:42:49.120978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-21T17:42:49.105129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-05-21T17:43:11.350077+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py syncdb` by siddharth.s1312@gmail.com
2015-05-21T17:43:19.065121+00:00 heroku[run.1581]: Awaiting client
2015-05-21T17:43:19.221034+00:00 heroku[run.1581]: Starting process with command `python manage.py syncdb`
2015-05-21T17:43:19.353332+00:00 heroku[run.1581]: State changed from starting to up
2015-05-21T17:44:00.997798+00:00 heroku[run.1581]: State changed from up to complete
2015-05-21T17:44:00.976815+00:00 heroku[run.1581]: Process exited with status 0
2015-05-21T17:44:16.011664+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blooming-shore-2021.herokuapp.com request_id=b1447909-82f6-4654-b95b-64b4b8d8d959 fwd="182.69.224.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-21T17:44:16.957534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blooming-shore-2021.herokuapp.com request_id=95473cab-2df1-400d-b1d9-5c215ba31252 fwd="182.69.224.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-21T17:44:30.807983+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/accounts/login" host=blooming-shore-2021.herokuapp.com request_id=01d0c136-ccff-4917-9fd5-b48bd184cd16 fwd="182.69.224.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-21T17:44:31.816726+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blooming-shore-2021.herokuapp.com request_id=e80757dd-4633-4968-8898-528189b7eeb2 fwd="182.69.224.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-05-21T17:51:58.391779+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by siddharth.s1312@gmail.com
(defcon)siddharth@s7h:~/Documents/python/defcon/s7h$
```